# calling function with new operator not returning value?

Tags: javascript, object

I have following javascript code

```js
    var foo = function(a, b) {
      var sumn;
      sumn = a + b;
      return sumn;
    }
    
    var k = new foo(2, 3);

    console.log(k);
```

this is not returning value as sum? what is solution for this?

Comment: `New` creates a new object using foo as prototype for it. Are you trying to call the function? if so, don't use new just code `var k = foo(2,3);`

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL: `foo` is not the prototype. It is the constructor. It may have a prototype assigned to `foo.prototype` but in this case it does not so it inherits directly from `Object`

Comment: @slebetman: All functions created in your code have a `.prototype`. The prototype of the new object in the question will be `foo.prototype`, which then inherits from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @squint: Yes but that's not the point. The point is `foo` is not the prototype. `foo.prototype` is. What `foo` is is a constructor

Comment: @slebetman: Sure, but nor is `Object` the prototype. That too is a constructor. The prototype chain is `obj -> foo.prototype -> Object.prototype -> null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the object you created with `this`

```
var foo = function(a,b){
  this.sumn = a+b;
}
var k = new foo(2,3);
console.log(k); // > foo {sumn: 5}
console.log(k.sumn);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the `new` keyword.

New code:

```
var foo = function(a,b){
   var sumn;
   sumn = a+b;
   return sumn;
}
var k = foo(2,3);
```

The `new` keyword is used for creating new instances of objects. You can read more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Answer (score 1):

You dont need new for calling a function.

```
 var foo = function(a,b){
  var sumn;
  sumn = a+b;
  return sumn;
}
var k = foo(2,3);
console.log(k);
```

Answer (score 1):

The below example calls the function, performs the addition and returns the value.  You dont need "New" keyword

As per below example the output is 7.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>




<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function foo(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = foo(4, 3);



</script>

</body>
</html>
```